# Como exibir as postagens de uma página do facebook?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Quero exibir as postagens de uma FanPage do facebook em um app.

Já andei pesquisando e algumas pessoas me ajudaram e disseram para usar a API do facebook. Pis bem, estou usando, mas, como o facebook não ajuda ninguém, venho aqui pedir a ajuda de vocês.

Estou usando o código abaixo, mas a partir dai como faço para os posts aparecerem?

PS: já tenho o token de acesso mas não sei como usá-lo.

```
new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/251217778341818/feed",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                try {
                    String titulo = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Carlos, você havia dito que "vou importar 'HttpMethod.GET' ele da erro". Qual é o erro? Descreve melhor sua dúvida que daí a resposta fica mais simples e objetiva.

Comment: Conseguir resolver Bruno, não sei como mais consegui kkkkkk acho que era somente a versão da api mudei da 4.0.0 para a 4.1.0

Comment: Legal Carlos, valeu.

Comment: mas ainda não sei como pegar as informações e exibir os posts, e o token de acesso já tenho mas não consigo setar @BrunoCésar

Answer (score 1):

O Facebook disponibiliza API para você ter acesso a estas informações.

No seu caso, para listar o feed de uma fan page, há o *serviço* [`/page/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed) na **Graph API**. Neste caso tudo no feed é listado, incluindo updates de status e publicações de outros usuários.

Veja a variância `/page/posts` para ter apenas os posts publicados pela página.

Retirando da documentação de referência, um exemplo em javascript seria:

```js
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        // faça seu trabalho aqui
      }
    }
);
```

E este outro no SDK android:

```java
new Request(
    session,
    "/{page-id}/feed",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // faça seu trabalho aqui
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Na [documentação de referência](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) você consegue encontrar toda a informação necessária para utilizar a API, inclusive como obter o `{page-id}`.

Como você citou as tags [web](/questions/tagged/web) e [android](/questions/tagged/android), veja os SDKs [javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) e [android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android)

Comment: já tentei mas esse método Callback() não é reconhecido.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSilva qual versão do `Android SDK` você tentou?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSilva a versão do SDK do facebook. Provavelmente está usando a `4`, devido a versão do android. Para a versão `4` do SDK do facebook, use [`GraphRequest`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/GraphRequest.java) no lugar de `Request`.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSilva o `session` é o [`AccessToken`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/)

Comment: ok!! mas ai o quando vou importar 'HttpMethod.GET' ele da erro..

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSilva atualiza sua pergunta (ou crie outra) com mais detalhes do que você já tentou, erros, etc., que atualizo a pergunta.

Comment: pronto, atualizei a pergunta